# Вывод колонок в цикле

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть [сайт](http://www.sotmarket.ru/) интересует вывод категорий, то есть он выводит категории в колонку, как категорий становится примерно 15, он создает новую колонку и начинает продолжать там, Помогите с построением  : ) желательно рекурсией

Comment: Demos, все равно выводится все в одну колону. код видимо правильный, но не хватает всего лишь css стиля) добавил во второй див style="float:left" но неполучилось

Comment: Спасибо! Спасибо! Спасибо! Спасибо! Спасибо! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div width="820">'; // Основной див
    for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){ //5-колонок
        for ($k=1; $k<=15; $k++){
            echo '<div width="164">';//Див одной колонки
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo '<a href="'.$row["link"].'">'.$row["link_name"].'</a><br/>';
            }
            echo '</div>';//Закрыли див колонки
        }    
    }
echo '</div>'; // Закрыли основной див
```

Comment: Это не мой сайт : ) я просто хочу сам построить цикл) и выводить так же категории в колонках

Comment: А, понятно. Ну делайте один див общий. В нем, допустим, 5 колонок, каждая колонка - это тоже отдельный див с float:left. И вот в каждый див вы в цикле выводите пункты меню, родитель (основной див) при этом по высоте должен тянуться.

Comment: Могли бы вы написать код? я сюда пришел за примером : ) пожалуйста.
код html и php

Comment: Исправил ответ. Примерно так. Код упрощен (просто понять смысл);

Comment: Вывелось все в один ряд: ) показать не могу,все на дэнвере, к вашему коду я добавил только sql запрос в базу.

Comment: Ну мой пример подразумевает, что у вас 5 основных категорий (каждая в совем диве). Уточните как у вас в базе линки разбиваются по категориям и что вы хотите видеть в каждой колонке?

Comment: У меня в базе нет дочерних элементов, есть только поля, name,id,text и все, и я хочу что бы эти категории шли как на том сайте который я показал, в колонках, по 15 штук

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: Итерация свойственна человеку, рекурсия божественна.

— L. Peter Deutsch

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$maxRowCount = 15; //максимальное число строк
$rubrik      = array(); //массив с рубриками
//Определяем неоходимое число колонок
$maxColCount = ceil(count($rubrik) / $maxRowCount);
//Вывод в таблицу

echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxRowCount; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $maxColCount; $j++) {
        if (array_key_exists($i + $j * $maxRowCount, $rubrik)) {
            echo '<td>' . $rubrik[$i + $j * $maxRowCount] . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: чет код не вставляется- подскажите как прально его написть?

Comment: Выделить код и нажать кнопку "10101"

Comment: спс DemoS)